# Changing key of array beeing pushing into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I've done some searches but can't seem to find someone with the same problem as I. I can't figure out how to change the key of an array that's beeing pushed into another array.

Example.

```
    $array1
    $array2

    array_push($array1, $array2);

    $array1 [
       "0" [
        //the data in array2
       ]
    ]
```

I want to change the key value where it says "0". Anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Just don't use `array_push`. Or do you want to change the kay after the element has been added?

Comment: Hi @fschmengler! I didn't think about that solution, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this?

```
$array1['your-key'] = $array2;
```

Comment: Oh, that was really smart. It fixed everything. Don't know how I couldn't think about this solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can not change a key directly. Instead you would insert the same data under the new key and remove the old key.

For example:

```
$array['new_key'] = $array['old_key'];
unset($array['old_key']);
```

Alternatively, instead of using array_push(), you can set the array key directly:

```
$array1['new_key'] = $array2;
```

I encourage you to read the [PHP Arrays docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) as arrays are a foundational element of PHP.